# Regex: split new lines between constant words

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Given

```
Word1   content1 content1 content1
       content2 content2 content2
         
          content3 content3 content3
Word2
```

I want to extract as groups content1, content2 and content3. Could you help to make a regex for that? I tried:

`Word1[\s:]*((?P<value>[^\n]+)\n)+Word2` with gms flags, but it didn't help. I need regex for python re module.

Comment: The blank line before the `content3` line doesn't match the pattern because `[^\n]+` requires each line to contain something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "Word1   content1 content1 content1\n       content2 content2 content2\n          content3 content3 content3\nWord2"
match = re.search(r'Word1[\s:]*((?:.+\n)*)Word2', text)
if match:
    print([s.strip() for s in match.group(1).splitlines()])
```

See the [Python](https://ideone.com/j0uRBi) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ky06O9/1).

Output:

```
['content1 content1 content1', 'content2 content2 content2', 'content3 content3 content3']
```

*Details*:

- `Word1` - a `Word1` string
- `[\s:]*` - zero or more whitespaces and colons
- `((?:.+\n)*)` - Group 1: zero or more repetitions of one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, followed with a newline char
- `Word2` - a `Word2` string.

Then, if there is a match, `[s.strip() for s in match.group(1).splitlines()]` splits the Group 1 value into separate lines.

An *alternative* solution using the [PyPi regex library](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) can be

```py
import regex
text = "Word1   content1 content1 content1\n       content2 content2 content2\n          content3 content3 content3\nWord2"
print( regex.findall(r'(?<=Word1[\s:]*(?s:.*?))\S(?:.*\S)?(?=(?s:.*?)\nWord2)', text) )
```

See the [Python demo](https://tio.run/##ZY/BDoIwEETvfMWGC1tiSIAbselHcPBgPRip2gS3TdkDfn0VQT10Ti@Tyc6sf/LdURujfXgXGIK5mTljMzNIyA8uDDUAXByxIa5T0ASrNqNJ4Rf5p9oUNC1lTZ75YIlxHVJdLQ3nccRQoNrLz5yjnrpTiWrqqlIJoXtUb9K9UKjk196uiWIHyy8CRIwv). *Details*:

- `(?<=Word1[\s:]*(?s:.*?))` -  a positive lookbehind that requires a `Word1` string, zero or more whitespaces or colons, and then any zero or more chars as few as possible immediately to the left of the current location
- `\S(?:.*\S)?` - a non-whhitespace char and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible till the last non-whitespace char on the line
- `(?=(?s:.*?)\nWord2)` - a positive lookahead that requires any zero or more chars as few as possible and then a newline char and `Word2` word to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Better extract to group everything between 2 words and then split it with new line symbol.

```
first_key = "Word1"
second_key = "Word2"
common_regex = r"{first_key}[\s:]*(?P<value>.+){second_key}"
regex = common_regex.format(first_key=first_key, second_key=second_key)
lines = [x.group("value").strip() for x in re.finditer(regex, text_piece, re.DOTALL)]
if lines:
    lines = lines[0].split("\n")
else:
    lines = []
print(lines)
```